# why php dynamic value does not display (echo)?

Tags: php, wordpress

the "echo $FacebookURL" does not display but if I move it to the inner most "foreach" it  works. I need to display after all foreach are completed. note: [the conditional below is valid]

```
$acf_metas = ['FacebookURL','SpotifyURL'];

foreach ($acf_metas as $acf_meta) {
    foreach ( get_field($acf_meta, 95013) as $k => $v) {
        ///set dynamic value
       ${$acf_meta}  = ( $k ==='main_url' ? $v .' -- ': false );
       // displays here ok 
       // echo $FacebookURL;
    }

}
//display dynamic value here does not display [the conditional above is valid]
echo $FacebookURL;
```

Comment: What does `get_field($acf_meta, 95013)` return? It looks like you're probably overwriting it after you've already found `$k === 'main_url'`. Just `break` out of the inner `foreach`, or if `get_field()` returns a single value/pair, remove the inner loop entirely.

Comment: You are overwriting the value in the foreach, add a check if that variable is already set then don't overwrite.

Comment: Is the inner foreach loop required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be overwriting the value of `$FacebookURL` in the foreach at every iteration. This way, it becomes `false` at a certain point of time and does not `echo` any output. To see values at each iteration, do

```
 var_dump($FacebookURL);
```